# Only select id's for which all factors in another column are equal

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread("id col2
       1    A
       1    A
       2    B
       2    A")
test$col2 <- as.factor(test$col2)

   id col2
1:  1    A
2:  1    A
3:  2    B
4:  2    A
```

From the data above I would like to simply select all columns for which the factor values in `col2` are equal, so only `id==1`, because the factors are both `A`. For `id==2`, the factors are not equal.

How should I do this?

Comment: So will each id have exactly two rows? Can an id have less or more than 2 rows? What's the logic then?

Comment: Each id will have the same number of rows (but not necessarily 2).

Comment: What did you try and where are you having issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr`, with `n_distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(col2) == 1)

#   id col2 
# 1  1    A    
# 2  1    A
```

---

In `data.table`, with `uniqueN`:

```r
library(data.table)
test[, .SD[uniqueN(col2) == 1], by = id]

#   id col2
#1:  1    A
#2:  1    A
```